# Smart Card local authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, smartcard

Is it possible to use smartCard for local authentication ?

So that, rather userID/password combination, an user can authenticate himself by inserting card and by providing it's PIN number.

RDesktop, Vmware view or other applications have an option to get logged in by smart-card only.

But how about local Linux authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup PAM to do that via PAM-PKCS11 (or alternatively using [PAM-P11](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512093343/http://www.gooze.eu/howto/smartcard-quickstarter-guide/smart-card-initialization)).

Once PAM knows how to verify your credentials against your smartcard, you can use that to login.